# How to get wifi signal strength of a router in android program in real time?

Tags: android, wifi, router

Using BroadcastReceiver() in wifimanger,i am able to get RSSI strength for every 4-5 seconds.
But i need it in real time.
Can i get the strength in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to start a scan with the WifiManager [getScanResults](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29):

```
final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
```

However, note that it returns the **latest** results which might be sooner *or* later than 4-5 seconds ago. But at least you obtain the most recent results.

**Edit**

You cannot get signal strength results in real time because there is no continuous scan.

If you must, you can initiate a scan with [startScan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan%28%29), but you will have to wait for the *asynchronous event sent on completion of the scan*.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
yes, that is what i tried already . I am getting results for every 4 seconds.
But i want the results atleast for every second or may be in real time.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and I found a decent solution.

If you use an Asynchronous task and run a loop that gets an updated RSSI on every iteration, you can update the UI with `onProgressUpdate()`.

I added a `Thread.sleep(500)` in my loop so it updates every half second.

If you have more questions I'd be glad to help.